# For a vector space, given two automorphisms show the following

Tags: linear-algebra

For a vector space, $E$, with $f$ and $g$ being two automorphisms on $E$ such that $f \circ g = Id_{E}$, the identity mapping. Show that

1. $\ker(f) = \ker(g \circ f)$
2. $\newcommand{\Img}{\operatorname{Im}}\Img(g) = \Img(g \circ f)$
3. $\ker(f) \cap \Img(g) ={0_E}$

For 1. I went about this the following way - $f$ is an automorphism, meaning that it is a linear, bijective mapping on $E$, meaning it has an inverse and is so full rank. This means that $\ker(f) = 0$

\begin{align}
\ker(f \circ g) &= \ker(Id_{E}) \\
&= 0 \\
&= \ker(f)
\end{align}

For 2. I approached it the following way

\begin{align}
\Img(g) &= \Img(f \circ g) \\
&= \Img(Id_{E}) \\ 
&= \Img(g)
\end{align}

This is because $\dim(\ker(Id_E)) = 0$, meaning that $\dim(\Img(Id_E)) = \dim(E)$

I took this approach but otherwise wouldn't have an idea how to solve this (inluding part 3.) so would be grateful for the communities thoughts. This is from [Mathematics for Machine Learning Q2.18](https://mml-book.github.io/book/mml-book.pdf).

Comment: Part 3 is not a claim so there is nothing to show. What is $\ker(f) \cap \operatorname{img}(g)$ supposed to satisfy?

Comment: Also, are you sure that $f$ and $g$ are supposed to be automorphisms as opposed to _endomorphisms_? As you rightly note the kernel of an automorphism is necessarily trivial.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. I have amended part iii), thanks for catching this. On your second point, the book clearly states they are *automorphisms*

Comment: Is there a typo in the first line of your displayed equations for part 2? Did you mean for the composition to go the other way?

Comment: Does the order of composition matter here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $f$ and $g$ are automorphisms, then so is $f \circ g$ (an inverse is given by $g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$). But now any automorphism satisfies $\ker(f) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Im}(f) = E$, hence all three claims follow immediately. The equations you have written all amount to this more or less, although you do not need to consider dimension at all.

Why this question is about automorphisms instead of endomorphisms is a mystery to me.